# Definite integral $\int_1^2 \sqrt{1+\left(-x^{-2}+x^2/4\right)^2}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble solving this integral. It relates to an arc length question. I tried Wolfram|Alpha, but when it solves it doesn't give me the option to view step-by-step.

**Integral:**
$$
\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{1+\left(-x^{-2}+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^2}\,dx
$$

Original question:

$$
y=\frac{1}{x} + \frac{x^3}{12}
$$

Find the arc length of the function on [1,2].

I used the equation:

$$
L = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}
 dx$$

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks. I'm reading your code to learn for future reference.

Comment: using Wolfram for the indefinte integral give a long solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%281%2B%28x%5E%28-2%29%2Bx%5E2%2F6%29%5E2%29+dx

Comment: @Stacksofoverflow You can simply hover over anything that is mathematically typeset and right-click: `Show Math As > TeX Commands`. That will show you how the equation or whatever it is you are looking at is typeset. Alternatively, you can simply look at the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1177227/revisions) for questions to see how someone wrote something up.

Comment: It does seem like something you would only like to compute numerically. Unless you are a CAS, Newton or something similarly close to infinitely powerful ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks @therapist

Comment: @String ok I'll post the original arc length question, I'm probably approaching it incorrectly.

Comment: @String Unless you're Cleo. Then you can find closed-form solutions of integrals with no problem at all (but never ever the step-by-step ;)).

Comment: The derivative of $x^{-1}$ is $-x^{-2}$

Comment: Yeah I realized this as I edited, thanks @Dr.MV sloppy mistake.

Comment: There are very few of these problems for arc length that work out nicely.  Miss a sign, and you have one that doesn't work out in closed form.

Comment: @GEdgar Ok, I'll re-attempt it now that I have cleared the calculation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying the integrand proceed as follows.$$1+\left( -x^{-2}+\frac14x^2\right)^2=1+\left(\frac{x^4-4}{4x^2}\right)^2=\frac{(x^4+4)^2}{16x^4}$$Then after taking a square root, the integrand simplifies to $$\frac{x^4+4}{4x^2}=x^{-2}+\frac14x^2$$which is trivial to integrate.

Comment: But the square root?

Comment: He included the square root, just didn't show it in the calculations.

Comment: Yes.  The integrand includes a square root.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the square, you can incorporate the $+1$ term into the expansion and then neatly factor everything into a quantity that has a simple square root. $$1+\left(-x^{-2}+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^2 = 1+\left(x^{-4}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^4}{16}\right) \\ = x^{-4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^4}{16}  \\ = \left(x^{-2}+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^2$$ and hence $$
\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{1+\left(-x^{-2}+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^2}\,dx
 = 
\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\left(x^{-2}+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^2}\,dx
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Dr.MV provided me with the solution, thanks for your help though