# Find the exact length of the arc of this curve

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, exponential-function

**$y = 2e^x + (1/8)e^{-x}$** ... on the interval $[0, \ln(2)]$

I know am supposed to user the Arc Length formula, but I'm not sure if I have the derivative of this function correct.

I came up with:

$$f'^2 (x)= 4e^{2x} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{64} e^{-2x}$$

I'm really rusty on this stuff though and am probably wrong.

And even if this is right, I'm not sure what to do next with all that + 1 under the square root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**:$$1+(f'(x))^2 = \left(2e^x + \frac{1}{8}e^{-x}\right)^2$$

Comment: what happened to the +1?
Can you show how this is true? My algebra clearly needs some work.

Comment: The $+1$ combines with the $-1/2$ in $(f')^2$ to give $+1/2$.  Then $1 + (f')^2 $ is a perfect square of the form shown above.

Comment: @nukeguy Now I see it, man, I'm never going to spot that by myself in a billion years...

Comment: A billion years?  Now that you have seen this one, also consult http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177227/ and maybe you can remember this trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formulae:

$$\int_a^b \sqrt{y'(x)^2+1} \, dx$$

This is arclength for cartesian coordinates.
Evaluate derivative $y'$,  square it and add one,
should be:

$1+\left(2 e^x-\frac{e^{-x}}{8}\right)^2=\left(2 e^x+\frac{e^{-x}}{8}\right)^2$

Now use formulae from above.

Comment: Ok, this is what I had then, but I wasn't sure what to do next so I multiplied it out, and it's messy. Is that what Im supposed to do?

Comment: @aSilveira Yes, i think so!

Comment: @nukeguy Thank's, now I see it.